# How to create Oracle minus-delimited datetime format regex?

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g

My table has got several columns. The most important in this example are 2 of them. I have the following string in DB row:

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| id |                                         info                                         | value |  
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| 10 | {"userId":"550","start":"2020-01-10 14:07:29","end":"2020-01-10 14:07:34","count":4} |   123 |  
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

What I want to do is to extract from this string `start` date only where another column has got exact value and order it by this extracted date desc.

In first step I have already tried to extract olny date from string but it is not working. The code is following:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(info, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" from my_table WHERE value = 123;
```

The thing is that this regex is working till I have no minus inside. I mean - regex for this is working correctly `[0-9]{4}` - but if I add minus than it's not.

I have Oracle 11g.

Comment: What is your Oracle version? `11g` ? `12c`?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy `11g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the regular expression `[{,]\s*"start"\s*:\s*"((\\"|[^"])*)"` to find the key-value pair with the key `start` and a quoted value and extract the first capturing group to find the value.

This will find the correct value for a given key regardless of whether the order of the JSON is changed.

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, info, value ) AS  
SELECT 10, '{"userId":"550","start":"2020-01-10 14:07:29","end":"2020-01-10 14:07:34","count":4}', 123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, '{"count":1,"end":"2020-02-03 12:34:56","userId":"551","start":"2020-01-02 01:23:45"}', 456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, '{"userId":"552","otherData":"\"start\":\"1970-01-01 00:00:00\"","start":"1999-01-01 00:00:00","end":"2000-01-01 23:59:59","count":42}', 789 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT id,
       value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( info, '[{,]\s*"userId"\s*:\s*"((\\"|[^"])*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         AS userID,
       TO_DATE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( info, '[{,]\s*"start"\s*:\s*"((\\"|[^"])*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS start_dt,
       TO_DATE(
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( info, '[{,]\s*"end"\s*:\s*"((\\"|[^"])*)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS end_dt,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( info, '[{,]\s*"count"\s*:\s*(\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )
         AS cnt
FROM   test_data;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | VALUE | USERID | START_DT            | END_DT              | CNT
> -: | ----: | :----- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :--
> 10 |   123 | 550    | 2020-01-10 14:07:29 | 2020-01-10 14:07:34 | 4  
> 20 |   456 | 551    | 2020-01-02 01:23:45 | 2020-02-03 12:34:56 | 1  
> 30 |   789 | 552    | 1999-01-01 00:00:00 | 2000-01-01 23:59:59 | 42
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4dc959e5aae8f89c507a7376253e4854)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of problem do you have with your regexp.

But maybe you should try something what is more readable.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('{"userId":"550","start":"2020-01-10 14:07:29","end":"2020-01-10 14:07:34","duration":4,"batchTotal":1}', '{"userId":"(.*?)","start":"(.*?)","end":"(.*?)","duration":([0-9]+),"batchTotal":([0-9]+)}','\2') from dual
```

Moreover you can extract different part of info changing numbers \1,\2,\3,\4,\5 in regexp_reaplce

Comment: This will fail if the JSON key-value pairs are in a different order and will get incorrect values if there is another key-value pair between the keys you are expecting (i.e. `..."start":"2000-01-01 00:00:00","other":"abc","end":"2001-01-01 00:00:00",...` will get `2000-01-01 00:00:00","other":"abc` as the value for `start`)

Comment: @MT0 I know, but i haven't said it's universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(info, 
                      '.*start":"(.*)","end".*',
                      '\1') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" 
  FROM YOURTABLE
 WHERE CONDITIONS;
```

Might work for You if You don't mind there is no specific regexp for the date format, AND You are sure that there's no other info in between the `start` and `end` keywords.

Note, this is a greedy regexp, You might want to adjust it.

Comment: This will fail if the JSON key-value pairs are in a different order and, as you mention, will get incorrect values if there is another key-value pair between the keys you are expecting (i.e. `..."start":"2000-01-01 00:00:00","other":"abc","end":"2001-01-01 00:00:00",...` will get `2000-01-01 00:00:00","other":"abc` as the value for `start`)

Comment: @MT0 I tried to point it out in the ``You are sure...`` part too.